# Cannot boot Ubuntu after sudden blackscreen

Tags: boot, 22.04

I went through a black screen and then there it shows an error when booting and I cannot enter the GUI of Ubuntu, but I can still give command through terminal command.

The error includes several lines, the first parts are basically:

> ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package(***ptrval***)(20230331/dsargs-301)

and then:

> psmouse serio1:elantech: elantech_send_cmd query 0x02 failed.
> psmouse serio1:elantech:failed to query capabilities.

What may be the problems and can I solve them?

Comment: Which GPU? Nvidia?